# Set Integrate term for PID controller

Tags: differential-equations

I want to use `Integrate` in a differential equation.
But my code doesn't work. My code is like this:

```
ClearAll[Kp, Kd, Ki, xd, x, F, Sol, t]
Kp = 100;
Kd = 5;
Ki = 1;
xd[t_] := Sin[t] + Cos[t/2] + 2 Sin[t/3];
F[t_] := -Kp*(x[t] - xd[t]) - Kd*(x'[t] - xd'[t]) - 
Ki*Integrate[(x[s] /. Sol - xd[s]), {s, 0, t}];
Sol = NDSolve[{x''[t] + x'[t] + x[t] == F[t], x'[0] == 1, 
x[0] == -1}, x, {t, 0, 10}];
Plot[{x[t] /. Sol, xd[t] /. Sol}, {t, 0, 10}, 
PlotStyle -> {{Black, Thick}, {Red, Dashed}}]
```

My problem is with the integral term. If I use `Ki = 0`, then my equation can be solved, but if I choose a non-zero number my code doesn't work.
Please help me adjust my code so that it works in this case.

Comment: The problem is that you're using `Sol` inside the equations that are used to compute `Sol` - that's not going to work (for `Ki=0`, the problematic term drops out, which is why it works in that case)

Comment: yes i use Sol because i want use integral of x[t] in my equation. how can i use Integrate that it works. with and without Sol my code is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Turn your integro-differential equation into an ordinary ODE. Here's the setup:

```
Kp = 100;
Kd = 5;
Ki = 1;
xd[t_] := Sin[t] + Cos[t/2] + 2 Sin[t/3]
F[t_] := -Kp (x[t] - xd[t]) - Kd (x'[t] - xd'[t]) - Ki Integrate[x[s] - xd[s], {s, 0, t}]
```

Then, your ODE is:

```
x''[t] + x'[t] + x[t] == F[t]
```

Of course, the above ODE won't work because the [`Integrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integrate) needs the functional dependence of `x` on `s`. On the other hand, we can differentiate `F[t]` to obtain:

```
F'[t] //TeXForm
```

> $-5 \left(x''(t)+\frac{2}{9} \sin \left(\frac{t}{3}\right)+\sin (t)+\frac{1}{4} \cos
>    \left(\frac{t}{2}\right)\right)-100 \left(x'(t)+\frac{1}{2} \sin \left(\frac{t}{2}\right)-\frac{2}{3} \cos
>    \left(\frac{t}{3}\right)-\cos (t)\right)-x(t)+2 \sin \left(\frac{t}{3}\right)+\sin (t)+\cos
>    \left(\frac{t}{2}\right)$

and the functional dependence of `x` is no longer required. So, the ODE to solve becomes:

```
sol = NDSolveValue[
    {
    x''[t] + x'[t] + x[t] == f[t], x[0] == -1, x'[0] == 1,
    f'[t] == F'[t], f[0] == F[0]
    },
    x,
    {t, 0, 10}
];
```

Visualization:

```
Plot[{sol[t], xd[t]}, {t, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> {{Black, Thick}, {Red, Dashed}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. your solution is completely true.